# Marry and come to France with partner

Tags: france, indonesia

I am a Mauritian employed on a scientific-chercheur visa in France. I will be getting married soon to my fiancee who is an Indonesian.  I'm still deciding where to be legally married based on where the procedures are simplest. I know that Mauritius it is straight forward while in Indonesia it is really complex. I would really want to be legally married in Mauritius but I have a question.

If I marry my fiancee in Mauritius, once married, it might take time before she gets the Mauritian nationality as it depends on the PM office. She will get residence in the meanwhile. For her to come to France with me, can she make her French visa application for "regroupement familiale" from French Embassy in Mauritius itself or does she has to go to Indonesia to do this ?

Comment: If she has official residence in Mauritius then she should be able to avail herself of consular services at a French consulate in Mauritius.  This should be clear on the consular website, but i don't have time to look it up right now.  (Generally, one must reside in the consulate's jurisdiction, so a Ghanaian residing in Nairobi would be required to apply in Nairobi and would be unable to apply in Ghana.)

Comment: the issue is that i'm not sure if she gets her residence permit so quick, she will be able to stay in Mauritius because she has a marriage certificate, with only the marriage certificate, can she use the consular services of France in Mauritius ?

Comment: I'm not sure. In theory, as long as she resides there legally, they should help her.  In practice, though, I don't know how they determine that (i.e., whether they will accept the marriage certificate as proof of legal residence).  Have you tried asking the consulate?